# How would one go about creating an iOS app to measure the speed of an object (specifically a baseball) using the iphone's camera?

Tags: ios, camera

Assuming I was perpendicular to the flight of the object, I would need to be able to:

1. identify and track the object.
2. Figure out the distance the object travels
3. Figure out the time it takes to travel.

Any ideas about how to go about this? Anything else I'd need to think about?

Comment: Please see this: http://xkcd.com/1425/ What you are asking is actually a very difficult problem.

Comment: Without having a point of measure in the background like a board with marked out lines, it would be difficult. You would probably be relying on using distance from moment of release to plate, or something similar and then using a... wow there are A LOT OF VARIABLES... If you figure it out, let the world know. It's a pretty good idea.